# Choose the correct statement.

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, contest-math, problem-solving

Suppose $x,y\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $x\neq y$ then which of the following statements are true?

A)$2sin(x+y)<sin2x + sin2y$ for all $x,y$

B)$2sin(x+y)>sin2x + sin2y$ for all $x,y$

C)There exist $x,y$ such that $2sin(x+y)=sin2x + sin2y$

D)None of these.

Based on the given problem I can only derive that expanding any of the equation we get option C as correct for $x=y$ but we cannot use it as $x\neq y$. So how should I solve the given problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the auxiliar function $$f(x,y)=2\sin(x+y)-\sin(2x)-\sin(2y).$$

Using the properties
$$
\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y),
$$
$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $\sin(2y)=2\sin(y)\cos(y)$,
your auxiliar function simplifies to
$$
f(x,y)=2\sin(x)(\cos(y)-\cos(x))+2\cos(y)(\sin(x)-\sin(y)).
$$

**Corrected:** (using @peterwhy tip) So, since $f(x,y)>0$ for $0<y<x<\pi/2$ and $f(y,x)=f(x,y)$, we prove that that $f(x,y)>0$ for $x\neq y$ so that B is indeed the right statement.

Disclaimer: The condition $x,y\in (0,\pi/2)$ assures that $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(y)$ are positive quantities).

Comment: You are indeed right. I forgot such detail. I will reformulate the proof.

Comment: The given answer is option B(I am unable to derive). Even I also got option c as my answer but clearly $x\neq y$ and $x,y\in (0,\pi/2)$ hence option C is not correct.

Comment: In principle, it suffices to prove that $\cos(y)>\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)>\sin(y)$ to prove that $f(x,y)>0$, and hence, that option B is correct. But this is only true or $x>y$ but not for $x\neq y$.

Comment: Can you please re write the proof of your solution @Nelson Faustino. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I made the correction above.

Comment: Nice observation, @peterwhy! I forgot it.

Comment: I've already corrected, using your tip.

Comment: Now I understand why the earlier trouble: because $\sin(x+y)$ should be $\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the LHS $\sin (x+y)$ and the RHS $\sin 2x + \sin 2y$,

$$\begin{align*}
& 2\sin(x+y) - \sin 2x - \sin 2y\\
 &= 2\sin x \cos y + 2\cos x \sin y - 2\sin x \cos x - 2\sin y \cos y\\
&= 2\sin x (\cos y - \cos x) + 2 \sin y (\cos x - \cos y)\\
&= 2(\sin x - \sin y) (\cos y - \cos x)\\
&> 0
\end{align*}$$

The final inequality is because either

- $0< x < y <\pi/2$, then $\sin x < \sin y$ and $\cos y < \cos x$; or
- $0< y < x <\pi/2$, then $\sin x > \sin y$ and $\cos y > \cos x$.